# Problem when building master-detail relationship

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

When trying to build master-detail relationship by wizard nothing happened - the form did not accept new relation .

It must create relation under relations list, but it is not created.
When trying to build relationship manually, I got message

> Error while parsing the join condition

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship is created between **form items**, not **table columns**. For example, if there are column names named `master.department_number` and `detail.department_number` while you decided to rename items to `:master.deptno` and `:detail.deptno`, you'll have to join latter, not the former: `:master_deptno = :detail.deptno`

*Sometimes* datablock name makes trouble; if that's your case, omit block names in relationship, i.e. just use `:deptno = :deptno` (looks kind of *stupid*, but - it helps).

Apart from that, the Wizard is quite successful in creating master-detail relationship. Check whether master block already contains triggers it creates (e.g. `on-populate-detail`). If so, either remove them or rename them, and then run the Wizard again.

---

If querying detail block returns all rows instead of the ones that satisfy relationship condition, double check code Wizard created. If you can't find the reason, try to create a `PRE-QUERY` detail-block level trigger and put

```
:detail.deptno = :master.deptno;
```

in there; then run the form again and see what happens.

Comment: i removed old relationships and rebuild it again .the relation has built .but now when i query the detail block fetch all records regardless of the condition .why? for example all records in employee table regardless deptno

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: thank you so much ,as always your solutions work 